# display a date from the other calendar as selected

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I have two calendar, when I select fist calendar value then my second calendar will shows previous calendar value +2 as selected ( i.e. when I select 2/07/2012  from first calendar then my second calendar will shows 4/07/2012 )
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to add days or months?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new date by adding the appropriate amount of seconds:

```
NSDate *newDate = [selectedDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*2];
```

and use that date as the basis for your new calendar.